# Root directory and on page word count

Tags: seo, keywords, navigation

I have a page featuring previews of weekly sporting events

**Example:**

week-1 round-1 will have 7 fixtures I will write about a 1000 word previews about each fixture. Week-2 round-2 has 7 fixtures I will again write previews for all of the fixtures:

**The Problem**

At the moment the page word count is reaching something close to 15'000 words, because I am keeping all of my previews on one page i.e domain.com/previews.php Also keep in mind I'm using the same 2 or 3 keywords throughout the page, but I'm not keyword stuffing since it is descent high quality content.

It is easy for the user to find the selected fixture they want to read because of some javascript I am using so user experience is not a problem

**My Question**

Should I rather change my root directory structure to example:

**previews** -> round1 -> round2

rather than just domain.com/preview.php as it is at the moment.

The only reason I am keeping it on one page at the moment is because of the 15'000+ word count of the page, and if I understand correctly Google loves high quality content (which I believe mine is) add to that a high word count of 15'000 plus words I believe it can only do the pages'ranking good? *Also can word count and keyword usage on a page be seen as excessive?*

**Or am I thinking wrong here and should I rather change my root directory to the above example?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High quality content is important, number of words is not.

You mention that user experience is not a problem, but I would consider size of document and loading time, plus potential overload of the browser with a lot of JS running a possible problem on the horizon.

Although you have many words on that page, and you provide a way to find what the user is looking for, it's easier with some divisions. We can not tell you what division because I don't know the content, but consider that. There would be a lot of improvements, not just loading time, but finding things will be easier and you would have more pages with high counts of hits.

Plus you could add more words if that is specially relevant for you, for the content or for the user.

Conclusion, if you keep everything working right, there is no need for splitting the content, but doing so, would have many benefits, now and in the future.